# SQL find rows that have adjacent number

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that looks more or less like this:

```
+----------+-------+
| position | group |
+----------+-------+
| 1        | a     |
+----------+-------+
| 5        | b     |
+----------+-------+
| 6        | b     |
+----------+-------+
| 7        | c     |
+----------+-------+
| 8        | b     |
+----------+-------+
```

I want to `SELECT` combinations of rows that have adjacent positions within the same group. For example, given the table above, the output of the query should be:

```
+----------+-------+
| position | group |
+----------+-------+
| 5        | b     |
+----------+-------+
| 6        | b     |
+----------+-------+
```

Performance is a bit of an issue because the table has 1.5 billion rows, but position and group are both indexed so it's relatively quick. Any suggestions on how to write this query? I'm not sure where to start because I don't know how to write a `WHERE` statement that involves multiple rows of output.

Comment: What do you mean with "adjacent". What if the group on position 1 whould be "b" as well. Is your desired output then 1,5,6? First I thought the position numbers shouldn't have any gaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `lag()` and `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(group) over (order by position) as prev_group,
             lead(group) over (order by position) as next_group
      from t
     ) t
where prev_group = group or next_group = group;
```

If by "adjacent" you specifically mean that the position differs by one (rather than being the closest value), then I would go for `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.group = t.group and t2.position = t.position - 1) or
      exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.group = t.group and t2.position = t.position + 1);
```

Comment: This did the trick, I was actually looking for positions differing by exactly one, so the second solution worked well (and fast!) for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct T1.position, T2.group from
T as T1
inner join
T as T2
on(T1.group=T2.group and t2.position=t1.position+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use subselect like this:

```
select * from mytable m1
where (select count(*) from mytable m2 where m2.position = m1.position + 1 and m2.group = m1.group) > 0
```